# How to get SharePoint 2010 site mobile enabled?

Tags: 2010, error

When I access my SP2010 site from a Smart Phone browser (Android or iOS), I get following error:

[image: Error]

What could be the issue here?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this an internal site requiring login?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites. It has the following URL: http://intranet.mysite.com

Comment: Does it require you to log in to get to your site from a non-mobile device?

Comment: Yes! I have to log in to get into the site.

Comment: You also may need an app to help you with login, there are several good ones available in either the Android or iPhone markets. Browsing a SharePoint site that requires login is different from browsing an anonymous facing public site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

Insert the following in the **configuration/system.web** section of the webapplication's web.config:

```
<browserCaps>
<result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
<filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
</browserCaps>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a hidden feature which manages the mobile redirect, try

in powershell

```
disable-spfeature -identity MobilityRedirect -url http://addressofsite
```

using stsadm

```
stsadm -o deactivateFeature -n MobilityRedirect -url http://addressofsite
```

HTH

Comment: I've try this, but it still redirect. Stsadm return success.